# Why the transaction reverted when I try to sell tokens on uniswap v2 router2, but success on browser？

Tags: web3js, uniswap, transfer

I am using web3 to send transaction to `uniswap v2 router2` to sell my tokens for ETH, with both the `sold token` and `WETH` approved for router2 with amount of `uint256max`, and I set    `amountOutMin` to 0 for least slippage. However I got my txn failed for `Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'`.But succeed later using browser, with same function and barely the same parametes. I just can't figure out why this happen, can somebody help me?

[Failed txn](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf4d2a870cc671d1ef78efbb5a8d1a31a2e1bba43d8a86408d127c15fda8f1c87)
0xf4d2a870cc671d1ef78efbb5a8d1a31a2e1bba43d8a86408d127c15fda8f1c87

[Successed txn](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xffc998042f9b37d047c17122c9093e5cfb664dc8a76114150fc31148ca77cb2d)
0xffc998042f9b37d047c17122c9093e5cfb664dc8a76114150fc31148ca77cb2d

[Approve txn](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x85c3089fa86d5a977ef6ebb9c0f66f0fba2c69e665c75d3711a6c06734be0dad)
0xc277632bff264ae04dc76579802d1b6d5f2f8052a48fe7c176b71bd8b0bc3a7c

Comment: It seems to be one of those tokens that charge fees when making a transfer. One difference is failed transaction doesn't set the minimum output. Did you try setting a reasonable value as minimal output amount?

Comment: Yes, i set it to zero

Comment: Can you try setting the output to some value above zero? My guess is that the code enters some corner case when the it is zero that make the whole transfer fail.

Comment: Thank you! It seem that the problem has been fixed(at least it works well so far)